# How do I remove the whitespace above the first text in an article?

Tags: margins, article

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

This code leaves a very big whitespace above foo.
Why is this and how do I make it smaller?

`\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}` (thanks for the tip  cmhughes) gives me

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with space? Do you mean the margin size?

Comment: adjust the page size using `geometry`. If you use `\documentclass{article}\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
` then you'll have a nice visualization of the current page setup

Comment: @azetina That's exactly the question. I don't know why this white space is there. If I knew it was f.e. the margin size, I could look into how to change that value, but I don't know what it is that causes it.

Comment: The extra white space is usually for headers and footers like footnotes or for example with the fancy page style the headers and footers. You can use: `\usepackage[top=length,bottom=length]{geometry}` or the sort. Do you have experience with the geomtery package?

Comment: No, I'm afraid I had no experience with it before your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is enough smaller?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=0pt,bmargin=90pt,lmargin=90pt,
rmargin=90pt}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```